# Return all matches in columns using one criterion (from drop down on another sheet)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I am having two tables, one table (table 1) below is main data, separated into many columns and blocks per 10 rows in one, as you can see A2:A11, A12:A21 and so on (many rows and columns) ... In Column A are unique numbers, but one number per block as a unique, and all other information in other columns can differ, sometimes will be more data sometimes not. The data is always same structured.

[image: Table 1]

What I am looking is to have report / printable sheet where I will have all my columns on one sheet, but in a Column A2 for instance drop down list that will use all unique numbers from main data table and populate all matches on report page, same as it is on picture below. There are many columns that should work automatically when I choose something from "Number" drop down. The trick here is, there must be 10 rows per block also, I have organized it as it should be, but I can't figure out how to populate using functions. So, you can imagine clicking one drop down and getting those lists updated without scrolling endlessly through columns and rows on main data table...

Where I have a problem is that I am getting matches only for first rows but not whole rows (or all rows where matches are) ...

using this function:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Datum];SMALL(IF(Table1[Nummer]=Printable!$A$2;ROW(Table1[Nummer])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Nummer];1;1))+1);1))
```

If someone can help me out, I would be happy!

[image: Report page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula. After putting formula to cell drag down and across as needed. I have tested this formula in `Excel2013` and with range (not as table). So, you have to adjust formula for table. I suggest you to first test the formula in single sheet like my screenshot and if it is successful then go for table in `Report` sheet.

```
 =INDEX(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($G$2,$A:$A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH($G$2,$A:$A,0)+9),ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I wanted! I underestimated the power of INDEX/MATCH function... thanks a lot! Have a great weekend!